# Purpose of NextJS production build while source code also in server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have static and server side rendering (getServerSideProps) in my NextJS application. My `npm run start` will run `next build && next start -p 3902`.

My questions are

1. Do we really need to deploy the whole root folder to server to get NextJS app running or just upload the `.next` folder will do?
2. Uploading the whole root folder will expose the source code right?
3. Lastly the server side rendering meaning the code only store in server instead of client side?

Thanks in advance